# insert images into mysql database blob data type

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have picturebox and a label with path of picture location..
in mysql database i have field 'Photo' with 'Blob' Data Type
and iam using this code to insert data to database :

```
Try
    MysqlCon = New MySqlConnection("Server=" & XIP & ";Database=" & XDB & ";User Id=" & XUser & ";Password=" & XPass & ";")
    MysqlCon.Open()
    MysqlCmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO staff(
                            Full_Name,
                            Full_Name_T,
                            Gender,
                            Num_ID,
                            Position,
                            Photo) VALUES 
                            ('" & txtfname.Text & "',
                            '" & txtfnamet.Text & "',
                            '" & cmbgender.Text & "',
                            '" & txtnumid.text & "',
                            '" & cmbposition.Text & "',
                            '" & lblphotopath.Text & "')", MysqlCon)
    MysqlRdr = MysqlCmd.ExecuteReader
    MysqlCon.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    Me.Enabled = True
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbNewLine & "Try Again or Call Admin." & vbNewLine & "ERR.06")
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

what iam trying to do is insert image to 'Photo' field using code above.

What should i add to my code above? or what should i change?

Comment: Firstly, why are you calling `ExecuteReader` when you're not reading any data? If you're not querying the database then the aptly named `ExecuteNonQuery` is the method you should be calling.

Comment: Secondly, and this is critical to your question, you need to learn how to use parameters in your ADO.NET code.  Check this out for the how and why: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: As for the question, check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469562-Saving-Images-in-Databases&highlight=

Comment: While it's not essential, I would also recommend that you acquaint yourself with the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` class as well as the `String.Format` method and, if you're using VB 2015 or later, string interpolation.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thats why iam asking this question.. i never insert image to database before and i think there is someway to insert image without using parameters, but if my code is not possible to insert image then.. just for this case i will using parameters or something else.. thanks.

Comment: it's a better practice to use parameters instead of inline code. You will avoid sql injection. if you want to add the blob object, you will have to change your photo into a byte array.

Comment: Also, unless the images are very small (under 100k), it's generally considered poor practice to store them in the database as opposed to simply storing a path to the file system.

Comment: "i think there is someway to insert image without using parameters"  There isn't but, even if there was, you shouldn't use it because you should ALWAYS use parameters. Don't use parameters just this time. Use them EVERY time. To do otherwise is to be a bad developer. For instance, you are taking unsanitised text from several `TextBoxes` there and a malicious user could manipulate that to delete everything from your database. If you know that can happen - which you now do - and continue to code without using parameters then you deserve bad things to happen to your data.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well.. maybe i'm used to not using parameters so i'm comfortable with that. But I just read a bit about the parameters and yes using parameters is much better than not using it. Maybe in the future I will always use the parameters for security reasons and stability. And thanks for the comments.

Comment: We pretty much all start out doing what you're doing here, myself included. I'm not criticising for that. Once you know that there's a better alternative though, there's no good reason to not change the way you do things. If you'd followed the link I provided that, as I said, explains not only how to but why to use parameters, you would know that the code you have might actually crash your app on some data, even if there was no security risk. I do have an issue when information is provided and ignored.